# How can I find which key exists in dict without if statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a dictionary and know that only one of N keys exists in that dictionary. The task is to find and save the value of the existing key.

I wrote the following bruteforce code but I believe there should be a nice oneliner or something:

```
final_key = None
for key in ['aa', 'bbb', 'cccc', 'ddddd', 'e']:
   if key in dict:
      final_key = key
      break
```

Comment: Why no `if` statements? Just make that a named function, no need to make everything one liner (which will likely be at the cost of efficiency). I'd prefer such straight forward code (it will even be simpler, as you can do `if key in dict: return key` in a proper function.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a set operation:

```
set(dict).intersection(['aa', 'bbb', 'cccc', 'ddddd', 'e'])
```

Comment: More concise: `set(dict).intersection...`. Be warned about `dict` usage though.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like:

```
next(x in your_list if x in dict)
```

It generates an iterator and will find just the first element of it.

Comment: But there is an `if` there.

Answer (score 1):

That snippet iterates over dictionary keys, and returns the key included into given list.

```
next(
   x for x in
   dictionary.keys()
   if x in ['aa', 'bbb', 'cccc', 'ddddd', 'e']
)
```

Comment: But there is an `if` there.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete the answer, by no means is this a good method.

```py
try:   
    dict[key] 
except KeyError:
    print("Key doesn't exist")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `filter` along with `get` method, to find the key of the dictionary:

```
final_key = list(filter(lambda key: not dict.get(key,None) is None, ['aa', 'bbb', 'cccc', 'ddddd', 'e']))[0]
```

**Note:** You should not use `dict` as a variable name, as it is a reserved Python keyword.

Answer (score 0):

No if-statements? Try the following:

```
i = 0
while yourlist[i] not in yourdict: i+=1
final_key = yourlist[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

just simple in python3

```
dict.__contains__('your key here')
```

and in python2

```
dict.has_key('your key here')
```

it will give you value True or False

Comment: You'll still need an `if` and a loop to use these. It's not really different than the `key in dict` statement.

Answer (score 0):

#### One-liners without if-statements are not better code.

Consider a traditional, documented, clean function:

```
def find_first(candidates, collection):
  """Find the first element of candidates also in collection"""
  for k in candidates:
    if k in collection: return k
  return None # or raise a KeyNotFound exception!
```

Or some (untested) one-liner such as:

```
next(set(candidates).intersection(set(collection))
```

Which code would you rather want to *debug* in one year? Which would you rather want to *optimize* if it were too slow (the one-liner supposedly is several times slower).